# How to run a MFC application exe file with c++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am new to MFC and C++. A MFC application was given to me, ssentially what I am trying to achieve is to run this MFC application from my standard C++ code in another project that will be build into a library. This c++ code perform some simple if else logic where it decides if the MFC application should run or not. Could someone explain how I could achieve this?

Assume: 
MFCApplication.h and MFCApplication.cpp is in project one.

Assume:
My project (project 2) involves

DoWork.cpp with body

```
if(some_logic)
{
MFCApplication x;
x.run();
.
.
.
x.terminate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same for any program, not just an MFC program. To run any application your program should call the CreateProcess API with the full path and filename of the exe file you wish to run.

Comment: I guess I should be a bit more detailed. I would like to be able to essentially get an instance of this application in my code so that I can call some its functions as well.

Comment: Operating systems don't work that way. If you have an application (an EXE file), you can run it, and possibly talk to it via some inter-process communication mechanism it supports (if any). If it's a shared library (a DLL), you can load it into your process and call its functions. You cannot do the latter with an EXE.

Comment: @Igor Your final sentence is misleading. You can `LoadLibrary` an EXE in the same way you can a DLL. Both are PE images, there really is no difference.

Comment: You can only `LoadLibrary` an EXE for the purpose of accessing its resources, or perhaps inspect its PE structure. But you can't call functions in it. For one thing, EXEs don't typically export any functions in the first place. For another, they don't typically have a relocation table, and it's highly unlikely that you would be able to load it at  its preferred address. Now, it's possible, in theory, to build an EXE that exports functions and has a relocation table - but at this point, you might as well just make it a DLL and be done with it.